# Providing type in generic argument when using Dapper QueryMultiple

Tags: c#, generics, runtime, dapper

I'm trying to create a layer over dapper and want to create a method that uses the QueryMultiple method. I want to map an incoming list of types in string format (determined at runtime) with the QueryMultiple's Read method.  When trying to use the Read method I can't find a way to make the generic argument accept the type i'm creating.

Can anyone please help me on how to correctly provide the type?

Here's the code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetNewConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(sql, param);
    foreach (string typeName in ListOfTypes)  //Iterate a List of types in string format.
    {
        Type elementType=  Type.GetType(typeName);
        var res= multi.Read<elementType>();  //Error: The type or namespace name 'combinedType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        //Add result to a dictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QueryMultiple.Read<T>()` method currently being used takes a generic type parameter which must be known at compile time. In other words, `elementType` cannot be used as a generic type parameter within the `<T>` parameter:

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType(typeName);
var res = multi.Read<elementType>(); // /Error: The type or namespace... etc.
```

If the type is not know until runtime, use the `QueryMultiple.Read(Type type)` method:

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType(typeName);
var res = multi.Read(elementType);
```

See MSDN for more info on [Generic Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!!! This really worked.  Also thanks for the generics explanation really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for following up!